# How can I make Firefox or Chrome ignore the system time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I'm setting Windows' time to 6 months before the current time, but when I try to visit any website I get the "Your clock is behind" error and SSL certificates not valid error.

How can I make Firefox and Chrome ignore the system time and use a time I specify instead?

Comment: How would the browser know what the current time it is if you changed it? No way to do this, it has to know the correct time to work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the help of [RunAsDate](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html), a freeware utility. It will allow you to fool any application into thinking that it's a time other than what your system says it is.

Keep in mind that this will not work with apps that fetch the current time from servers, rather than using the system time.

[image: Screenshot of RunAsDate]